# Online serial, higher dimensional cop & criminal imprisoned in our universe

Tags: story-identification

Sometime I think in the 2000s I read some online serialised SF. It has a number of threads that only meet fairly late in the piece.

One of the main threads was an alien higher-dimensional cop fighting an even-higher higher-dimensional criminal. (Memory says something like cop was 50 space dimensions and 5 time dimensions; criminal was +5 space and +1 time beyond that). Cop throws the criminal down into the "basement" of reality, the minimum possible that can support the mind: 3 space & 1 time. Cop must trap themselves with the criminal to imprison them.

The prisoner keeps thinking up ways to escape, and the prison seems to involve some kind of AI cosmic censor which progressively forbids things: superluminal travel, time travel, shifting sideways in parallel dimensions. The criminal rarely does anything themselves and indeed is hidden for most of the story. e.g. parallel world-shifting is a third party who are trapped here after the cosmic censor amends reality to forbid it.

In one of the other threads there is a superhero woman who appears to be basically invulnerable to everything. It is eventually determined that she has the properties of matter travelling at the speed of light from the perspective of "normal" matter.

Comment: I know exactly what you're asking about, but for the life of me, I can't remember the author, website or title. :-(.  The title may have been 1-2 words long, and I think they were scientific or mathematical terms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Fine Structure](https://qntm.org/structure)

By Sam Hughes.

> Fledgling physicist Ching-Yu Kuang has discovered a Rosetta Stone  for all
>   of physics, a treasure trove of advanced scientific
>   breakthroughs  beyond all imagination. Exotic energy, teleportation,
>   FTL, parallel universes  and near-infinitely more wonders are just
>   within reach; a promise of  paradise.
>
> But every attempt to exploit this new science results in sabotage, 
>   chaos  and destruction. And the laws of science themselves are
>   changing with each  experiment, locking out the new discoveries,
>   directly altering the universe  to make what should be possible
>   impossible. While Ching watches, humanity's  future is being stolen.
>
> Because there's something wrong with his world. There's a fundamental
>   flaw, a defect in its structure...

Comment: Wow! That’s it! Thank you so much!!